# Can the count() function work for getting the number of rows with a specific name?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a table types like this :

```
id     cat
_________

1        A

2        B

3        A

4        A

5        B
```

and the code i use to query the Database is something like this:

```
$query="SELECT*FROM types";

$res=myslqi_query($conn,$query)

while($row=myslqi_fetch_assoc($res){



          if($row['cat']==A){

               echo count($row['cat'];   

               };

};
```

i get an error with this type of code by the count()function .

Is it possible that insted of Displaying like AAA together just ti be able to display a number insted like 3 what i just want ?

Comment: You've got all sorts of things wrong with this code. `==A` should probably be `=='A'`, you're missing a `)` in the `count(` line, and you're `count()`ing on a string, which will fail (as it should).

Comment: I *suspect* you'll want to look into SQL's `GROUP BY` and do the count in the query itself, but it's a bit hard to figure out what your goal is.

Comment: Is what you actually need this...? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.phpy

Comment: @ceejayoz  want insted if echoing out  AAA as usally with this code if we remove the if statment , to be able to display the totall amount of the values in the 'cat' field only as a number . So if the are three Values with A that the result to be just the number 3

Comment: @burimrexhepi Simple: `SELECT cat, COUNT(id) AS count FROM types GROUP BY cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that insted of Displaying like AAA together just ti be able to display a number insted like 3 what i just want
>
> be able to display the totall amount of the values in the 'cat' field only as a number . So if the are three Values with A that the result to be just the number 3

Try

```
<?php
$rows = [
 ['id'=>1, 'cat'=>'A'],
 ['id'=>2, 'cat'=>'B'],
 ['id'=>3, 'cat'=>'A'],
 ['id'=>4, 'cat'=>'A'],
 ['id'=>5, 'cat'=>'B']
];


print_r( array_count_values( array_column($rows,'cat') ) );
```

Output

```
Array
(
   [A] => 3
   [B] => 2
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b2b6d34e032d57fde0247b3b9fcc3cdfc1635e0)

Where the value is the number of occurrences of each 'cat'

I don't know if that is what you want, but it's like magik..  No that was a joke it's just code.

Array Column returns only the values from a single column in a multi-dimensional array, so for this example it returns

```
[
   'A',
   'B',
   'A',
   'A',
   'B'
]
```

Then array count values, counts all the occurrences of each value in a single array, and gives us the result show at the beginning.

For this you need the whole results of the data from the database, So you can fetch them all with this `while($row=myslqi_fetch_assoc($res){` and add each row to result `$rows[] = $row` in the loop, or you can just do `$rows =mysqli_fetch_all($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Of course you could also do this just in MySQL

```
SELECT count(id) as total FROM types GROUP BY cat.
```

But whatever...

Cheers Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep it works thanks a loot ,these multidimensional arrays are hard to understand have to keep learning more